# How to calculate unknown resistance from known current in the vector-matrix form of Ohm's law

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, ohms-law, matrix

[image]

[image]

I was trying to answer this question (pic 1) using the following method (pic 2):

Step 1. Apply junction law to find the current vector.

Step 2. Apply loop law to find the voltage vector and resistance matrix.

Step 3. Convert Ohm's law from scaler form to vector-matrix form.

Step 4. Put everything in a calculator and it prints the answer.

This method works only when voltage vector and resistance matrix is given and current vector should be found. Now imagine this qustion is modified in this way "if 4/3 A flows through the (30 Ohm) resistor in the middle, what is its resistance"? The answer obviously will be 30 Ohm but how would I calculate it? Now my resiatance matrix is unknown as it has the last component missing and my current vector is also unknown despite the first component being known. How can this problem be solved in this situation?

Also is this true for all variables that whether it is a scalar, vector or matrix depends on context? Like electric field can be a scalar or a matrix in some situation instead of being a vector all the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your choice of example of unknown resistance, the central 30Ω one, is unfortunate, because the current through it is zero, and it can therefore have *any* value without changing the solution for any other variable in the system. It could even be removed and nothing would change.

You can't ever have anything but 0A through that resistor between B and H, and therefore any system of equations in which current through it is specified to be non-zero, will have no solution. I suspect you may be able to form a matrix equation for the system, but you will find that the matrix of coefficients is not invertible.

Being able to disregard that central 30Ω resistor makes the answer to the question "what is battery current?" rather trivial to calculate, by reducing the entire resistor network down to a single resistance, but this doesn't answer *your* question.

---

Your own matrix equation is a special case which *just happens* to have all the unknowns (the currents) on the same side of the equality, and therefore may be solved by taking the inverse of the resistance matrix.

Conveniently, it has the form \$\vec{V}=\vec{I}\vec{R}\$, in which you can clearly discern individual matrices representing voltages, currents and resistances respectively.

Your question amounts to asking "how do we solve the matrix equation if there are unknowns on *both* sides?". The answer is that you must perform whatever manipulations are needed to bring all unknown variables into a single matrix, and which also leaves you with a matrix of constants (which will need to be  be invertible). However, after you arrive at that state, the correlation between individual matrices with voltage, current and resistance will no longer be evident, since the matrices necessarily each contain a mix of coefficients of voltage/current/resistance.

I suppose it's possible to perform matrix manipulations to derive a form in which all unknowns are grouped within the same vector, but I wouldn't want to do that. I would rather write all equations from scratch, and derive the final vector/matrix form directly. I'll redraw your circuit with proper designators, and then rewrite mesh current equations with one unknown resistance \$R_1\$, and one extra *known* current, \$I_2\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB6j38.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$
\begin{aligned}
(I_1 - I_2)R_3 + (I_1 - I_3)R_4 + I_1R_6 -V_{BAT1} &= 0 \\ \\
I_2R_1 + (I_2 - I_3)R_5 + (I_2 - I_1)R_3 &= 0 \\ \\
(I_3 - I_1)R_4 + (I_3 - I_2)R_5 + I_3R_2 &= 0 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Now evaluate the coefficients of the unknowns \$I_1\$, \$I_3\$ and \$R_1\$, and group them to the left, with constants on the right. I won't show you all the steps involved, but this is what I got:

$$
\begin{array}{rcrcrlc}
(+130)I_1 &+ &(-30)I_3 &+ &(0)R_1 &= &+107.5 \\ \\
(-90)I_1 &+ &(-30)I_3 &+ &(+0.75)R_1 &= &-90 \\ \\
(-30)I_1 &+ &(+70)I_3 &+ &(0)R_1 &= &+22.5 \\ \\
\end{array}
$$

Matrix form:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
+130 &-30 &0 \\
-90 &-30 &+22.5 \\
-30 &+70 &0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
I_1 \\
I_3 \\
R_1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
+107.5 \\
-90 \\
+22.5 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Already you see that the matrices contain a mix of voltages and resistances, and the \$\vec{V}=\vec{I}\vec{R}\$ correlation is lost. It can still be solved though:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\begin{pmatrix}
I_1 \\
I_3 \\
R_1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
+130 &-30 &0 \\
-90 &-30 &+0.75 \\
-30 &+70 &0 \\
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
+107.5 \\
-90 \\
+22.5 \\
\end{pmatrix} \\ \\
&= 
\begin{pmatrix}
0.00853\dots &0 &0.00365\dots \\
0.00365\dots &0 &0.01585\dots \\
1.17073\dots &1.33333\dots &1.07317\dots \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
+107.5 \\
-90 \\
+22.5 \\
\end{pmatrix} \\ \\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
+1 \\
+0.75 \\
+30 \\
\end{pmatrix} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you a lot for this amazing answer. Basically, after applying the loop law the three equations need to be rearranged in such a manner that the unknown resistance becomes a component of the current vector. This will make sure that there will be no unknown components in the resistance matrix, right? I never thought it would be so simple. Thank you again for your time Mr Fitch.

Answer (score 0):

If one of the resistors, say Rx was unknown but you knew its current or the voltage over it and wanted to calculate the right Rx, you should calculate the Thevenin equivalent for the rest of the circuit. Then it's elementary to see which is the right loading resistor Rx to the calculated Thevenin equivalent. It may happen that no Rx is the right one. The Thevenin equivalent may have too high resistance or its source voltage may be too low.

Answer (score 0):

The question looks the way it does because it's meant to be solved quickly. Of course the question of how it's supposed to be solved using any particular method is still a good one.

Here's how I look at it:

- it's a Wheatstone bridge and is balanced since the ratios in the upper and lower branch are the same 3:1,
- thus no current across (vertically) through the bridge,
- top branch is 40Ω (30+10 in series), bottom branch is 120Ω,
- the bridge can be replaced by parallel combination 40||120 = (40*120)/(40+120) = 30Ω,
- there's an additional 10&ohm in series with the bridge, so the battery sees a 40&ohm (10+30) load;,
- the current is 1A=40V/40Ω.

That was the author's intention - it was supposed to be simple. Of course sometimes such easy problems happen by coincidence - but still, it's worthwhile to notice when it's easy and can be essentially solved just by looking at it.